# SQL Query - Distinct results

Tags: sql, join, correlated-subquery

I have the following two tables:

```
People [*ID*, Name] 
Pet [*PetID*, OwnerID, Species, Name]
```

(OwnerID is a foreign key of ID)

I would like the database to list each person and how many *different species* they own. For example, if Bob (ID 1473) owned a dog, cat and another dog the output should be:

```
ID    | No. of Species
----------------------
1473  | 2
```

I realize that this would require correlated sub-queries or outer joins, but I'm not exactly sure how to do that. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `count(distinct ...)` for that:

```
select  People.ID
,       count(distinct Species)
from    People
join    Pet
on      Pet.OwnerID = People.ID
group by
        People.ID
```

Comment: *'…to list **each** person…'*

Comment: @Andriy M: That would be `left join` I guess :)

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought. But the OP seems to have agreed with your choice instead. :)

Comment: Well it's close enough. And Andomar was first to answer, so I accepted this one :)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
Select ID,[No. of Species] from People 
inner join 
  ( select Count(Species) as [No. of Species],OwnerID from Pet  
   group by OwnerID) d 
on Id = d.OwnerID
```

Comment: But `count(*)` will count the number of pets, not the number of species?

Answer (score 1):

```
select people.name, count(distinct pet.species)
from people, pet
where people.id = pet.ownerid
group by people.name
```